# Parentheses around a matrix

Tags: matrices, parenthesis, parentheses

So this is the code that I have so far:

```
\[
  Y =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    Y_{1}   \\
    Y_{2}   \\
    \vdots \\
    Y_{n}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    42 \\
    33 \\
    75 \\
    28 \\
    91 \\
    55
  \end{bmatrix}\quad
  X=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & X_{11} & X_{12} & ... & & X_{1,p-1}\\
    1      & X_{21} & X_{22} & ... & & X_{2,p-1}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &     & & \vdots\\
    1      & X_{n1} & X_{n2} & ... & & X_{n,p-1}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 7  & 33\\
    1 & 4  & 41\\
    1 & 16 & 7\\
    1 & 3  & 49\\
    1 & 21 & 5\\
    1 & 8  & 31
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

And I want to write out this equation:

```
\textbf{b}=$(X'X)^{-1}(X'Y)$
```

I would like to put a parentheses around `X'X`, but how would I do that? 
like in this format:

```
([x][x'])<-big parentheses around matricies
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: to [create a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192), you need to have at least one empty line. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but the following might be sufficient to show you what you can do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Xmatrix}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 &  7 & 33 \\
    1 &  4 & 41 \\
    1 & 16 &  7 \\
    1 &  3 & 49 \\
    1 & 21 &  5 \\
    1 &  8 & 31
  \end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\Ymatrix}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    42 \\ 33 \\ 75 \\ 28 \\ 91 \\ 55
  \end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\[
  Y = \begin{bmatrix}
    Y_1 \\ Y_2 \\ \vdots \\ Y_n
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \Ymatrix
  \quad
  X = \begin{bmatrix}
      1    & X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1,p-1} \\
      1    & X_{21} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2,p-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &        &  \vdots   \\
      1    & X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \cdots & X_{n,p-1} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \Xmatrix
\]

\[
  \mathbf{b} = \bigl( X^T X \bigr)^{-1} \bigl( X^T Y \bigr)
\]

\[
  \mathbf{b} = \left( \Xmatrix^T \Xmatrix \right)^{-1} \left( \Xmatrix^T \Ymatrix \right)
\]

\[
  \mathbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \Xmatrix^T \Xmatrix
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \Xmatrix^T \Ymatrix
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Large braces or brackets around objects can either be achieved using "`\big` operators", `\left`...`\right` pairs, or `*matrix`-like environments.